# Distributed Cache Host Down

Tags: 2013, distributedcache

when I start the cache host  on the server with the below command

```
Start-CacheHost -Computername "name" -CachePort 22233
```

it immediately displays

> HostName : CachePort Service Name            Service Status Version
>   Info
>   -------------------- ------------            -------------- ------------ name:22233           AppFabricCachingService DOWN           3 [3,3][1,3]

When I check the logs I see

> AppFabricCachingService.Crash 
>     Param System.UriFormatException: Invalid URI: The hostname could not be parsed. at System.Uri.CreateThis

I am able to ping the hostname.

Can somebody point what is missing?

Answer (score 2):

Applied the App Fabric CU 5 , and it started working . More Info here [MSDN Forum](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sharepoint/en-US/5d872362-c2e8-4810-b7eb-4da6c95486c2/distributed-cache-host-down?forum=sharepointadmin)

Lesson Learned - Always Patch Your Servers

Answer (score 0):

### Check that the clusterConfig URL is correct.

Open `C:\Program Files\AppFabric 1.1 for Windows Server\DistributedCacheService.exe.config`. Find the `configuration` > `dataCacheConfig` > `clusterConfig` element and check that the hostname of the `connectionString` property makes sense, e.g.:

```
<clusterConfig provider="SPDistributedCacheClusterProvider" connectionString="Data Source=name.mydomain.local;Initial Catalog=SharePoint_Config;Integrated Security=True;Persist Security Info=False;Enlist=False;Pooling=True;Min Pool Size=0;Max Pool Size=100;PoolBlockingPeriod=Auto;Asynchronous Processing=False;Connection Reset=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=False;Replication=False;Connect Timeout=15;Encrypt=False;TrustServerCertificate=False;Load Balance Timeout=0;Packet Size=8000;Type System Version=Latest;Application Name=&quot;.Net SqlClient Data Provider&quot;;User Instance=False;Context Connection=False;Transaction Binding=&quot;Implicit Unbind&quot;;ApplicationIntent=ReadWrite;MultiSubnetFailover=False;TransparentNetworkIPResolution=True;ConnectRetryCount=1;ConnectRetryInterval=10;Column Encryption Setting=Disabled" />
```

...where `name` is the hostname of your server where the `SharePoint_Config` database is hosted and `mydomain` is your AD domain name. Particularly, you want to use the *fully qualified DNS hostname*, not the NetBIOS name, of the server.

More info: https://givenscj.wordpress.com/2012/11/24/sharepoint-2013-dcs-keeps-crashing-distributedcacheservice-exe-system-uriformatexception/